# Auto scaling button's width in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, button, scale, android-relativelayout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"/>

      <!--x7-->
```

I put 7 buttons in its relativelayout. And I'd like to adjust their 'width' to the same size to fit the screen. What should I do

Comment: is it necessary to put relativeLayout as parent ?

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" doesn't work?

Comment: If I can do it without relativeLayout, I won't put relativeLayout as parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` as a parent and can give `weight` and `weightsum` to achieve that, Using Relative layout you can't fit the entire screen or it may exceed the screen based on the device.

You can achieve this using LinearLayout like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="7"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome, If you feel it solves your problem, You can mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of displaying each button (height= match_parent), then use scrollview. I hope this helps